# Target Contact form redirect to a thankyou page

Tags: jquery, redirect, header, contact-form, window.open

Hi I would like somebody to help me in adding the function header(Location:thankyou.html) or some other function that redirects a succesfull sent email to a thank you page. I tried several methods on my script (which I downloaded pre-filled) and it does not work.

The script comes with 3 files: a targetform.js, a config_email.php and a engine.php

I hereby write the full script of the three files

**targetform.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//botton form click
$("#bottone-contact").click(function(){

$(this).hide(); 
$("<img src='Images/loader.gif' class='loader' />").appendTo("#contact");

var timer = 2000;

//associo variabili generali
var nome = $("#nome").val();
var messaggio = $("#messaggio").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var oggetto = $("#oggetto").val();
var informativa = $("#informativa").attr('checked');
//pattern email
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;


if(!emailReg.test(email)) {

     $("#bottone-contact").show(); 
     $("<div id='errori'></div>").appendTo("#contact").html("<span>Ooopsss! You may have typed your email in an uncorrect way! Check if the @ is present</span>").delay(2000).fadeOut(timer);
     $(".loader").hide();


} else if(informativa != "checked"){


    alert("You must accept the statement on the privacy data treatment in order to continue!");
     $("#bottone-contact").show();
    $(".loader").hide();

} else if   (nome == "" || email == "" )  { 


    $("#bottone-contact").show(); 
    $("<div id='errori'></div>").appendTo("#contact").html("<span>Fill in all the fields with the asterisk!</span>").delay(2000).fadeOut(timer);
    $(".loader").hide();



} //se ci sono campi vuoti
else { //se sono stati compilati tutti i campi
//chiamata ajax
$.ajax({

  type: "POST",

  url: "form/engine.php",

//il form invia i dati all'engine
  data: "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email  + "&messaggio=" + messaggio + "&oggetto=" + oggetto,
  dataType: "html",

    success: function(msg)
  {
          //Imposta il valore dei campi di testo come vuoto grazie a val()
          $(".loader").hide();
          $("<div id='risultato'></div>").appendTo('#contact').html("<span>Email sent with success!</span>").delay(3000).fadeOut(timer);
          $("#bottone-contact").delay(2000).fadeIn(); 
  },


  error: function()
  {
    alert("An unexpected error has occurred...."); 
  }
});


}//else controlli
}); //fine form


});//Fine Dom
```

**engine.php**

```
        <?php


        //Includo Variabili
        include('config_email.php');


        session_start();

            $nome       =   $_POST['nome'];
            $email      =   $_POST['email'];
            $oggetto    =   $_POST['oggetto'];
            $messaggio  =   $_POST['messaggio'];
            $ip         =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

          if (empty($_POST['nome'])):
                exit;
            else:
            //Codice normale di invio
          endif;

        //Verifica antispam 

        if($_POST['fred'] != "") {
            echo('<p style="color: #000; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Are you a spambot or are you using undesired spam techniques? Sorry but your email has not been sent</p>');    
        }


        else {



    //Invio la mail

    $to         = $tua_email;
    $sbj        = "Richiesta Informazioni - $sito_internet";
    $msg        = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body{
        font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial;
        color:#333;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
      <tr>
        <td width='121' align='right' valign='baseline'><strong>Nome:</strong></td>
        <td width='459'>$nome</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align='right' valign='baseline'><strong>Email:</strong></td>
        <td>$email</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width='121' align='right' valign='baseline'><strong>Oggetto:</strong></td>
        <td width='459'>$oggetto</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align='right' valign='baseline'><strong>Richiesta:</strong></td>
        <td>$messaggio</td>
      </tr>


        <tr>
        <td align='right' valign='baseline'><strong>IP Tracciato (per motivi di sicurezza):</strong></td>
        <td>$ip</td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><small>Powered by Targetweb.it | &copy; Copyright 2012 Riccardo Mel</small></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $from        = $email;
    $headers     = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers    .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"; //In certi casi con aruba se non viene formattata eliminare il \r per i permessi come ho fatto in questo caso
    $headers    .= "From: $from";

    mail($to,$sbj,$msg,$headers); //Invio mail principale.

    //Fine mail inviata a me




    //Inizio email di conferma
    $toClient        = $email;
    $msgClient       = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body{
        font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial;
        color:#333;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Versilia Rent</h1>
    <br />
    <h2>www.versiliarent.com</h2>


    <h2>Automatic response</h2>
    <br />

       <p>Thanks for contact us, $nome</p>
        <p>We received your email. We will answer as soon as possible.</p>  

    </body>

    </html>
    ";
    $fromClient      = $tua_email;
    $sbjClient       = "Response to your information request Versilia Rent";
    $headersClient   = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headersClient  .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headersClient  .= "From: $fromClient";

    mail($toClient,$sbjClient,$msgClient,$headersClient); //mail inviata al cliente

    //Fine email di conferma

    //Resetto errori

    session_destroy();

    exit;

    } //fine else del controllo antispam



    ?>
```

**config_email.php**

```
        <?php

        //file di configurazione variabili

        $tua_email = "n.pagnoni@alice.it";

        $sito_internet  =   "Versilia Rent";

        $grazie = "http://www.versiliarent.it";

    ?>
```

I imagine I should add somewhere the following

> header('Location: page.php');

I thought I should enter it in the section of the targetform.js file that gives instructions after the line

> success: function(msg)
>   {

but it does not work. I also tried a

> window.open

but again nothing.

Thanks for help!
(note: I write here since the author of the script did not answer yet to my questions and probably will do it in weeks)
Elena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I just added the following:

```
success: function(msg)
  {

          $(".loader").hide();
          $("<div id='risultato'></div>").appendTo('#contact').html("<span>Email sent with success!</span>").delay(3000).fadeOut(timer);
          $("#bottone-contact").delay(2000).fadeIn(); 
          window.location='http://www.versiliarent.com/thanks.html'
  },
```